# self signed IOS app can't be launch after shutdown or time period

Tags: ios, swift

To do a project for school, I need to make an IOS swift application and put it on my phone, my app works well after few questions here ^^ but I still have a little problem.

I auto signed my app by my ios account so I'm not into the developer's program (i didn't pay anything and isn't the purpose to pay something cause I'm a student). So I can have access to my app on my phone when I upload into it, I still have access to the app after the upload (without any mac nearby) but when my phone shut off (no more battery generally) it seems that the app can be launch again, it crashes before any opening. My idea is that the "Developer mode" (shown in settings) disappear after a shutdown or a certain time period. There is another way to counter this problem without paying the developer program?

Thanks.

Comment: For this you need to register yourself in developer's program. It gives you access for a limited time in your mobile. After a certain time it expire your developer certificate.

Comment: Apps developed with the free level need to be reinstalled every couple of days. Apps created with a paid membership run for 6 months or so